# MVC Page full of Unicode/Trash

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unicode, encoding

I'm working on a web app project with a team which is currently being migrated from ASP.NET to ASP.NET MVC Framework, and late last week, I was suddenly unable to properly load any of the MVC pages.

I can load any page still on the old framework just fine. When I try to load one of the updated pages, I get something along the lines of this:

> ��}�s�6���[��wr�xj-��l��z<����W����NW>��lf(R!)d6�oHJM�e����)5�D�Fw��h4y����?>[��,{��?�-�9��Q�~�����ˣb6O��N��:.ˢ<5/@��#+�f�ų��^ϋ�~f�E^Ӽ~��:M�� �Jc:?�Y#X��o{��I��Z_��`���v�ُ�L�

The trash content fills the page, and is different every time. The results are the same in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

The Live Headers extension for Chrome shows that I'm getting a 500 error when this happens. In Internet Explorer (and Visual Studio Page Inspector, which I suspect is using IE to render the page), the error actually shows up instead of filling the page with trash:

> ## ***Compilation Error***
>
> **Description:** An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> **Compiler Error Message:** CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> **Source Error:**
>
> ```
> Line 27:    using System.Web.Routing;
> Line 28:    using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
> Line 29:    using Newtonsoft.Json;
> Line 30:    using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
> Line 31:
> ```
>
> **Source File:** c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7bd9a704\8efd3118\App_Web__layout.cshtml.639c3968.skqnufwa.0.cs    **Line:** 29

Nobody else on my team is experiencing this issue. I have attempted:

- Restarting Visual Studio
- Rebooting my machine
- Deleting all project files and re-downloading them from our version control
- Replacing all files in `C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/` with a copy from one of my teammates who is not having this issue
- Deleting all files in `C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/`

The project references `Newtonsoft.Json.dll`, which is located in `$project_root/packages/Newtonsoft.Json.5.0.8/lib/net40`, which I deleted and re-downloaded during my troubleshooting attempts.

I've pretty much been stuck working on SQL queries for the backend due to this problem ([related question on dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66487/refactoring-in-subquery-avoiding-query-in-a-loop)); I can certainly do the work and I have work to do, but I would like to be able to resolve this issue and be capable of contributing to any part of the project.

Comment: The information provided is not enough and the issue needs additional research. As for output: in Chrome development tools (or Fiddler or any other web sniffer) check what is actual response coming. As for error itself: check if Newtonsoft.Json.dll is really located in /bin folder of your web application root after compilation. Also you could use [fusion log viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check why assembly loading failed (that could be due to usage of two different version of json.net assembly).

Comment: @mikalai, Manually copying the DLL into web project's `/bin` directory  worked. Looking closer at the Newtonsoft.Json reference properties, it's set to Copy Local: False. Deleting the manually-copied DLL, setting the reference to Copy Local: True, and rebuilding the solution solved the problem. Post as an answer and I'll accept it. :)

Comment: that's fine. Have you figured out the reason for 'encrypted' response?

Comment: @mikalai, No, I haven't discovered why most of the browsers give such as strange result page. To be perfectly honest, I'm just happy that I can test the MVC pages of our project locally again. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(So I'm copying a comment as an answer:)

Check if Newtonsoft.Json.dll is really located in /bin folder of your web application root after compilation.